# Is there anything in AngularJS that can help me get data to and from local storage?

Tags: angularjs

Some of my user screens have `select` tags looking like this:

```
<select
   data-ng-disabled="option.subjects.length == 0"
   data-ng-model="option.selectedSubject"
   data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.subjects">
   <option style="display: none" value="">Select Subject</option>
</select>
```

Rather than show the "Select Subject" default, is there a good way that I could check local storage and retrieve a value for my `select` that was stored the last time I made a choice?

Comment: checkout the localstorage module https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: There are probably a bunch of modules out there, or you can create your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check this one out. This is the best one I've found yet.
---> [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Here's a **[DEMO](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo.html)**

### Sample Code

```js
var YourCtrl = function($scope, localStorageService, ...) { 
    // To add to local storage
    localStorageService.add('localStorageKey','Add this!');
    // Read that value back
    var value = localStorageService.get('localStorageKey');
    // You can also play with cookies the same way
    localStorageService.cookie.add('localStorageKey','I am a cookie value now');
}
```